# Как в модели реализовать свойство на основе sql

Tags: laravel

Когда у нас простой тип отношений, все понятно:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Phone::class);
    }
}
```

А если я могу описать отношение только эскуэлом?

```
public function книги_полученные_в_библиотеке_маяковского_в_нечетные_выходные()
{
   $sql='эскуэл у меня есть, где брать user id?'; 
   return ???;
}
```

К примеру, в модели юзера я хочу иметь возможность увидеть что-нибудь не укладывающееся в рамки отношений на основе ключей, а вытаскиваемое сложным эскуэл-запросом. Ну например от юзера получить список полученных книг, причем в таблице выдачи книг нет id юзера, а только фио, год рождения (пример выдуманный, в реальности связь еще более витиеватая). Могу ли я это как-то реализовать, имея только текст sql, где брать user id, для подстановки?
С Ларавелом знаком к сожалению очень поверхностно, буду очень рад советам.

Comment: Возможно стоит продумать архитектуру бд. если у двух разных книг будут абсолютно разные пользователи но при этом полные тёзки?

Comment: Дайте кусок реального дампа.

Comment: Если перейти к реальному примеру, то есть таблицы "Табель учета", связанная таблица "Сотрудники", далее  "Дни работы сотрудника", в ней у дней есть код "работа в выходные дни". И есть отдельная таблица "Приказ о работе в выходные дни", в ней есть подчиненная таблица "дни_приказа". Я наверное смогу на таблице "Табель учета" штатными средствами сделать свойство "Выходные дни". А вот перейти к таблице "Приказ о работе в выходные дни", могу только с помощью эскуэла. Все это требуется чтобы запросив "Табель учета" иметь все данные, требуемые для построения отчета. (а приказы там нужны)

Comment: Действующего приложения пока нет.

Comment: Пересмотрите вашу структуру таблиц в базе данных, тут явно прослеживается нарушение принципов нормализации, для связи двух таблиц является обязательным иметь вторичный ключ в зависимой таблице, не выдумывайте свой велосипед